# Train/test division for each month in time series in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, train-test-split

I have time series data. Instead of using the first 80% of the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing, I want to split every month in that manner. The dataset contains multiple years of data. For every month I want to perform the split. Any knows how to this with for example the xgboost ml in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `stratify` parameter in the `train_test_split()` function.

So something like: `train_test_split(X, y, stratify=X['month_variable'])`.

That should give you a train and test split which is stratified with all the months in it.

If you want train and test sets which only contain a certain month, I would recommend you make different df's, so something like: `df_jan = df.loc[df['month_variable'] == 'january]` and then perform the `train_test_split` and build separate models.

Just depends on what you want.